# Cute, beautiful, pretty

Tags: meaning, word-usage

Is the following "formula" about girls true?

> pretty = beautiful or cute

I mean

> beautiful > cute

but for "pretty" there is override with both.

Comment: Beauty is in the eye of the beholder.

Answer (score 2):

A lot of people will have different ideas about how those words relate to one another. Some would say *pretty* and *beautiful* differ only in that the latter is more formal. Others would say that it's a matter of degree.

*Cute* is an awkward one to factor in, because it doesn't always mean the same sort of thing as *beautiful* or *pretty*. It can, and it can mean *handsome*, and it can mean the same as *cocky* or *mouthy*, or other terms with similar meanings (as in "don't get cute"). It can mean nice-looking in the sense that animals are that make people go "aww". It can mean behaving in a certain sort of supposedly-endearing way. You have to judge what it means from context.